# Adding views on a custom GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-layout

(note that I'm a total beginner in android programming)

I have a class that derives from GLSurfaceView.

What I would like is to place some views (image,text) on top of it. 
I managed to get the text view to position properly by using `textView.setPadding(300,0,0,0)`;

The problem is that I cannot get the image view to position properly. I've tried `imageView.layout(), imageView.setPadding()`.

Here is the code:

```
 ImageView imageView=new .... // Create and set drawable

 // Setting size works as expected
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
 imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

 surfaceView = new MySurfaceViewDerivedFromOpenGLSurface(...);

 setContentView(surfaceView);

 addContentView(textView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 addContentView(textView2, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
 addContentView(imageView, lp); // Add the image view
```

Is it even possible to position it properly this way without specifing the stuff in the XML file?

I saw an example in the sdk dev website that shows how to create views on the openGL surface view, but the problem is that I have a derived class and I don't know if I can specify it in the XML file (I have 0% experience in the XML, Eclipse handled everything for me so far).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll save a ton of headaches later by learning how to use xml layout. Specifying a layout for a custom view tripped me up too. This is how it works:

```
<view class="complete.package.name.goes.here.ClassName"
    android:id="@+id/workspace"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >        
</view>
```

So a really simple vertical layout for your app would be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <view class="package.name.to.MySurfaceViewDerivedFromOpenGLSurface"
        android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">        
    </view>     
</LinearLayout>
```

You can get a reference to anything in your layout files as long as there's an id:

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```